# The startofbiz command fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, derby, ofbiz, opentaps

I am a beginner user of ofbiz. I want to use startofbiz.bat to start ofbiz, but it fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Here is the output of my run, with the error message: (I deleted some common messages for the body is limited to 30000 characters)

```
Set OFBIZ_HOME to - G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0
Admin socket not configured; set to port 0
2015-11-26 09:33:27,093 (main) [    ContainerLoader.java:51 :INFO ] [Startup] Loading containers...
2015-11-26 09:33:27,398 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:178:INFO ] Auto-Loading component directory : [G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/framework]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,449 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [geronimo]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,471 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [sql]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,488 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [entity]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,504 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [catalina]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,974 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:277:WARN ] Location 'G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/applications/accounting/lib/cybersource' does not exist
2015-11-26 09:33:27,974 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:277:WARN ] Location 'G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/applications/accounting/lib/worldpay' does not exist
2015-11-26 09:33:27,974 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [humanres]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,991 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [order]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,991 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [marketing]
2015-11-26 09:33:27,991 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:277:WARN ] Location 'G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/applications/marketing/lib' does not exist
2015-11-26 09:33:28,006 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [commonext]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,006 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:178:INFO ] Auto-Loading component directory : [G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/specialpurpose]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,022 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [ecommerce]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,022 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [pos]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,038 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [hhfacility]
 Loading component : [myportal]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,085 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [webpos]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,085 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:239:INFO ] Loading component : [crowd]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,101 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:178:INFO ] Auto-Loading component directory : [G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps]
 Loading component : [translations]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,179 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:178:INFO ] Auto-Loading component directory : [G:/Develop/opentaps-1.5.0/opentaps-1.5.0/hot-deploy]
2015-11-26 09:33:28,210 (main) [ ComponentContainer.java:147:INFO ] All components loaded
Loaded ESAPI properties from classpath
  ========Master Configuration========
  |   LogEncodingRequired=false
  |   LogLevel=ALL
  |   MaxUploadFileBytes=500000000
  |   ResponseContentType=text/html; charset=UTF-8
  |   ValidExtensions=.zip,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.tar,.gz,.tgz,.rar,.war,.jar,.ear,.xls,.rtf,.properties,.java,.class,.txt,.xml,.jsp,.jsf,.exe,.dll
  |   Validator.AccountName=^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$
  |   Validator.CreditCard=^(\d{4}[- ]?){3}\d{4}$
  |   Validator.DirectoryName=^[a-zA-Z0-9.-\_ ]{0,255}$
  |   Validator.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
  |   Validator.FileName=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_ ]{0,255}$
  |   Validator.HTTPCookieName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,32}$
  |   Validator.HTTPCookieValue=^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/+=_ ]*$
  |   Validator.HTTPHeaderName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,32}$
  |   Validator.HTTPHeaderValue=^[a-zA-Z0-9()\-=\*\.\?;,+\/:&_ ]*$
  |   Validator.HTTPParameterName=^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,32}$
  |   Validator.HTTPParameterValue=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-\/+=_ ]*$
  |   Validator.IPAddress=^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
  |   Validator.Redirect=^\/test.*$
  |   Validator.RoleName=^[a-z]{1,20}$
  |   Validator.SSN=^(?!000)([0-6]\d{2}|7([0-6]\d|7[012]))([ -]?)(?!00)\d\d\3(?!0000)\d{4}$
  |   Validator.SafeString=^[p{L}p{N}.]{0,1024}$
  |   Validator.SystemCommand=^[a-zA-Z\-\/]{0,64}$
  |   Validator.URL=^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\:\'\/\\\+=&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
  |   event.test.actions=disable,log
  |   event.test.count=2
  |   event.test.interval=10
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.actions=log,disable,logout
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.count=10
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.interval=5
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.actions=log,disable,logout
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.count=1
  |   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.interval=1
2015-11-26 09:33:28,351 (main) [ClassLoaderContainer.java:51 :INFO ] CachedClassLoader created
2015-11-26 09:33:28,382 (main) [DelegatorFactoryImpl.java:30 :INFO ] Creating new delegator [default] (main)
2015-11-26 09:33:29,395 (main) [        ModelReader.java:149:WARN ] WARNING: Entity SalesOpportunityAndRole is defined more than once, most recent will over-write previous definition(s)
2015-11-26 09:33:29,395 (main) [        ModelReader.java:152:WARN ] WARNING: Entity SalesOpportunityAndRole was found in ComponentResourceHandler from XML file [crmsfa] with loaderName [main] and location [entitydef/entitymodel.xml], but was already defined in ComponentResourceHandler from XML file [order] with loaderName [main] and location [entitydef/entitymodel.xml]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,426 (main) [        ModelReader.java:149:WARN ] WARNING: Entity InvoiceItemAssoc is defined more than once, most recent will over-write previous definition(s)
2015-11-26 09:33:29,426 (main) [        ModelReader.java:152:WARN ] WARNING: Entity InvoiceItemAssoc was found in ComponentResourceHandler from XML file [financials] with loaderName [main] and location [entitydef/entitymodel.xml], but was already defined in ComponentResourceHandler from XML file [accounting] with loaderName [main] and location [entitydef/entitymodel.xml]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,567 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:533:WARN ] Conversion for complex-alias needs to be implemented for cache and in-memory eval stuff to work correctly, will not work for alias: statusDelay of view-entity ExampleStatusDetail
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortAssocFromView because one already exists with the alias name [sequenceNum] and field name [WEFROM(WorkEffort).sequenceNum], existing field name is [WEA.sequenceNum]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortAssocToView because one already exists with the alias name [sequenceNum] and field name [WETO(WorkEffort).sequenceNum], existing field name is [WEA.sequenceNum]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [facilityId] and field name [PROD(Product).facilityId], existing field name is [WE.facilityId]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [description] and field name [PROD(Product).description], existing field name is [WE.description]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [reserv2ndPPPerc] and field name [PROD(Product).reserv2ndPPPerc], existing field name is [WE.reserv2ndPPPerc]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [reservNthPPPerc] and field name [PROD(Product).reservNthPPPerc], existing field name is [WE.reservNthPPPerc]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [createdDate] and field name [PROD(Product).createdDate], existing field name is [WE.createdDate]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [createdByUserLogin] and field name [PROD(Product).createdByUserLogin], existing field name is [WE.createdByUserLogin]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [lastModifiedDate] and field name [PROD(Product).lastModifiedDate], existing field name is [WE.lastModifiedDate]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,582 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity WorkEffortProductGoods because one already exists with the alias name [lastModifiedByUserLogin] and field name [PROD(Product).lastModifiedByUserLogin], existing field name is [WE.lastModifiedByUserLogin]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,614 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity OrderHeaderItemAndShipGroup because one already exists with the alias name [statusId] and field name [OISG(OrderItemShipGroup).statusId], existing field name is [OH.statusId]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,614 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity OrderItemAndShipGrpInvResAndItem because one already exists with the alias name [acctgTagEnumId1] and field name [II(InventoryItem).acctgTagEnumId1], existing field name is [OI.acctgTagEnumId1]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,614 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity OrderItemAndShipGrpInvResAndItem because one already exists with the alias name [acctgTagEnumId2] and field name [II(InventoryItem).acctgTagEnumId2], existing field name is [OI.acctgTagEnumId2]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,614 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity OrderItemAndShipGrpInvResAndItem because one already exists with the alias name [acctgTagEnumId3] and field name [II(InventoryItem).acctgTagEnumId3], existing field name is [OI.acctgTagEnumId3]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,614 (main) [    ModelViewEntity.java:691:INFO ] Throwing out field alias in view entity OrderItemAndShipGrpInvResAndItem because one already exists with the alias name [acctgTagEnumId4] and field name [II(InventoryItem).acctgTagEnumId4], existing field name is [OI.acctgTagEnumId4]
2015-11-26 09:33:29,773 (main) [        ModelReader.java:390:INFO ] FINISHED LOADING ENTITIES - ALL FILES; #Entities=1021 #ViewEntities=371 #Fields=11099 #Relationships=3483 #AutoRelationships=2519
2015-11-26 09:33:29,835 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:245:INFO ] Doing entity definition check...
2015-11-26 09:33:29,835 (main) [ ModelEntityChecker.java:503:INFO ] [initReservedWords] array length=1023
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:248:WARN ] =-=-=-=-= Found 5 warnings when checking the entity definitions:
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:250:WARN ] [RelationNameNotUnique] Relation OrderItemBilling of entity InvoiceAndInvoiceItem is not unique for that entity.
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:250:WARN ] [RelatedOneKeyMapsWrongSize] The number of primary keys (4) of related entity OrderItemBilling does not match the number of keymaps (2) for relation of type one "OrderItemBilling" of entity InvoiceAndInvoiceItem.
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:250:WARN ] [RelationOneRelatedPrimaryKeyMissing] The primary key "orderId" of related entity OrderItemBilling is missing in the keymaps for relation of type one OrderItemBilling of entity InvoiceAndInvoiceItem.
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:250:WARN ] [RelationOneRelatedPrimaryKeyMissing] The primary key "orderItemSeqId" of related entity OrderItemBilling is missing in the keymaps for relation of type one OrderItemBilling of entity InvoiceAndInvoiceItem.
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:250:WARN ] [RelationFieldNotFound] The field invoiceItemSeqId was specified in the keymaps but is not found for relation OrderItemBilling of entity InvoiceAndInvoiceItem.
2015-11-26 09:33:29,931 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:260:INFO ] Delegator "default" initializing helper "localderby" for entity group "org.ofbiz".
2015-11-26 09:33:29,947 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:270:INFO ] Doing database check as requested in entityengine.xml with addMissing=true
2015-11-26 09:33:31,077 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:817:INFO ] Database Product Name is Apache Derby
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:818:INFO ] Database Product Version is 10.5.3.0 - (802917)
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:826:INFO ] Database Driver Name is Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:827:INFO ] Database Driver Version is 10.5.3.0 - (802917)
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:828:INFO ] Database Driver JDBC Version is 4.0
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:837:INFO ] Database Setting/Support Information (those with a * should be true):
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:839:INFO ] - supports transactions    [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:31,092 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:845:INFO ] - isolation None           [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:31,699 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1219:INFO ] Getting Column Info From Database
2015-11-26 09:33:32,543 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1313:WARN ] Error getting primary key info from database with null tableName, will try other means: java.sql.SQLException: Table name can not be null
2015-11-26 09:33:32,543 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1324:INFO ] Searching in 1015 tables for primary key fields ...
2015-11-26 09:33:33,874 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1332:INFO ] Reviewed 1930 primary key fields from database.
2015-11-26 09:33:33,905 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:260:INFO ] Delegator "default" initializing helper "localderbyolap" for entity group "org.ofbiz.olap".
2015-11-26 09:33:34,768 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1313:WARN ] Error getting primary key info from database with null tableName, will try other means: java.sql.SQLException: Table name can not be null
2015-11-26 09:33:34,768 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1324:INFO ] Searching in 3 tables for primary key fields ...
2015-11-26 09:33:34,783 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1332:INFO ] Reviewed 4 primary key fields from database.
2015-11-26 09:33:34,783 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:260:INFO ] Delegator "default" initializing helper "localderbytenant" for entity group "org.ofbiz.tenant".
2015-11-26 09:33:34,783 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:270:INFO ] Doing database check as requested in entityengine.xml with addMissing=true
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:817:INFO ] Database Product Name is Apache Derby
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:818:INFO ] Database Product Version is 10.5.3.0 - (802917)
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:826:INFO ] Database Driver Name is Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:827:INFO ] Database Driver Version is 10.5.3.0 - (802917)
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:828:INFO ] Database Driver JDBC Version is 4.0
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:837:INFO ] Database Setting/Support Information (those with a * should be true):
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:839:INFO ] - supports transactions    [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:845:INFO ] - isolation None           [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:851:INFO ] - isolation ReadCommitted  [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:857:INFO ] - isolation ReadUncommitted[true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:863:INFO ] - isolation RepeatableRead [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:869:INFO ] - isolation Serializable   [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:875:INFO ] - default fetchsize        [1]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:881:INFO ] - forward only type        [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:887:INFO ] - scroll sensitive type    [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:893:INFO ] - scroll insensitive type  [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:899:INFO ] - is case sensitive        [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:905:INFO ] - stores LowerCase         [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:911:INFO ] - stores MixedCase         [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:917:INFO ] - stores UpperCase         [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:923:INFO ] - max table name length    [128]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:929:INFO ] - max column name length   [128]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:935:INFO ] - max schema name length   [128]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:941:INFO ] - concurrent connections   [0]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:947:INFO ] - concurrent statements    [0]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:953:INFO ] - ANSI SQL92 Entry         [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:959:INFO ] - ANSI SQL92 Intermediate  [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:965:INFO ] - ANSI SQL92 Full          [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:971:INFO ] - ODBC SQL Grammar Core    [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:977:INFO ] - ODBC SQL Grammar Extended[false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:983:INFO ] - ODBC SQL Grammar Minimum [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:989:INFO ] - outer joins              [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:995:INFO ] - limited outer joins      [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1001:INFO ] - full outer joins         [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1007:INFO ] - group by                 [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1013:INFO ] - group by not in select   [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1019:INFO ] - column aliasing          [true]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1025:INFO ] - order by not in select   [false]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1034:INFO ] - named parameters         [ SKIPPED ]
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1040:INFO ] - alter table add column   [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1046:INFO ] - non-nullable column      [true]*
2015-11-26 09:33:35,178 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1084:INFO ] Getting Table Info From Database
2015-11-26 09:33:35,196 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1219:INFO ] Getting Column Info From Database
2015-11-26 09:33:35,383 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1313:WARN ] Error getting primary key info from database with null tableName, will try other means: java.sql.SQLException: Table name can not be null
2015-11-26 09:33:35,399 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1324:INFO ] Searching in 2 tables for primary key fields ...
2015-11-26 09:33:35,399 (main) [       DatabaseUtil.java:1332:INFO ] Reviewed 3 primary key fields from database.
2015-11-26 09:33:35,462 (main) [   GenericDelegator.java:309:INFO ] Distributed Cache Clear System disabled for delegator [default]
```

and on the console is the java exception:

```
 > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    > 
    >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
    > orAccessorImpl.java:62)
    >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
    > onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    >         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    >         at org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.initEntityEcaHandler(GenericDelegat
    > or.java:339)
    >         at org.ofbiz.entity.DelegatorFactory.getDelegator(DelegatorFactory.java:
    > 42)
    >         at org.ofbiz.catalina.container.CatalinaContainer.init(CatalinaContainer
    > .java:175)
    >         at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.loadContainer(ContainerLoade
    > r.java:189)
    >         at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.load(ContainerLoader.java:66
    > )
    >         at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.initStartLoaders(Start.java:260)
    >         at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:97)
    >         at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:411) 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26721
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unkn
    > own Source)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown 
    > Source)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(A
    > smClassInfo.java:308)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(A
    > smClassInfo.java:331)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.createClassInf
    > oFromStream(AsmClassInfo.java:790)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(A
    > smClassInfo.java:273)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getInterfaces(
    > AsmClassInfo.java:619)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.ClassInfoHelper.implementsInterface(
    > ClassInfoHelper.java:56)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPoin
    > tCompiler.collectCustomProceedMethods(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:237)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPoin
    > tCompiler.collectCustomProceedMethods(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:208)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPoin
    > tCompiler.initialize(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:149)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPoin
    > tCompiler.<init>(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:133)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.MethodExecutionJ
    > oinPointCompiler.<init>(MethodExecutionJoinPointCompiler.java:33)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.JoinPointFactory
    > .compileJoinPoint(JoinPointFactory.java:86)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager$Compil
    > edJoinPoint.<init>(JoinPointManager.java:262)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager.compil
    > eJoinPoint(JoinPointManager.java:251)
    >         at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager.loadJo
    > inPoint(JoinPointManager.java:118)
    >         at org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.aw$initJoinPoints(Delegat
    > orEcaHandler.java)
    >         at org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.<clinit>(DelegatorEcaHand
    > ler.java)
    >         ... 13 more
```

I analyzed the message, found the exception is thrown by org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler. , and before that there is ofbiz's warning:Error getting primary key info from database with null tableName.

So I am wondering does it mean that there is a problem such as 'table not generating', which is leading to the eca initializing problem?

It's the first time I am running ofbiz; I follow the step by step instructions from the website, but the exception came out, how to fix it?

Comment: what java version are you using ?   make sure you are on 1.6

Comment: I am now using java 1.8.0_66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opentaps does not support java sdk 8.  You should use jdk 6